# From $\tan(1/A) = \tan(1/B) + \tan(1/C)$ to $A + B + C = ABC$

Tags: trigonometry

In [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884642/an-equation-of-the-form-a-b-c-abc), the equation
$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{A}\right) = \tan\left(\frac{1}{B}\right) + \tan\left(\frac{1}{C}\right)$$ is said to imply
$$A + B + C = ABC$$
without any stated constraints.  Where does this come from, and is it even correct?

I must be misunderstanding the context here, because even with integers like $B = 4$ and $C = 5$, the equations disagree.

Comment: Even the solution in integers $\{A=3,B=2,C=1\}$ of $A+B+C=ABC$ fails to satisfy the tangent equation.